# GCM service does not work when offline[Android]

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using `GCM service` to send some notifications in my android application.The notifications are pushed to other android device perfectly if that device is online(Use `wi-fi` or mobile data).But if that device is offline, then the `GCM` push notifications does not get to that device after it get online.Is there any code that I should add specifically to do this task or any other configurations to be configured?

Comment: seriously? I mean you want to download something from network even if you are not connected?

Comment: @kiturk he wants notifications when device get connected again not when device is offline

Comment: @kiturk3 is right.I need the notifications to be received after the device get online.Currently it receive only if the device is online when the notification send.But if offline after we get online the notifications does not receive.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your message to be delivered on a device (that is currently offline) when it goes online. You can check the [Time-To-Live](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl) parameter in your request. This parameter tells the  GCM storage how long (in seconds) the message should be kept if the device is offline. It can be set up to a maximum 4 weeks which is also the default value if you don't specify one.